# How to emphasize text inside (innerText) a DIV with GWT or Javascript:

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, gwt

**How to emphasize text inside a DIV with GWT or Javascript:**

```
Element content = DOM.createElement("div");
content.setInnerText(contentString);
```

Which generates this DIV:

```
<div>test message test message</div>
```

I want to be able to emphasize some texts with this code (e.g. "`test`"):

```
<em>test</em>
```

**So the div will be like this:**

```
<div>
  <em>test</em> message <em>test</em> message
</div>
```

Comment: `content.innerHTML = contentString.replace(/\btest\b/g, '<em>test</em>');`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon thanks this worked. If you like you can put this as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve what you want in 2 steps.

First, don't use `setInnerText` since it will not interpret HTML. Instead, you should use `.innerHTML` property of the element.

Second, you can replace the desired word with a Regular expression. just wrap your word between the word delemiter (`\b`).

Final code looks like that :

```
content.innerHTML = contentString.replace(/\btest\b/g, '<em>test</em>');
```

In case you have multiple word to change :

```
content.innerHTML = contentString.replace(/\b(test|other words)\b/g, '<em>$1</em>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the format of just a part of the text, but you can change the innerHTML of your DIV to include the formatting, as you can see in the script part below.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="mydiv">test message</div>
 </body>

 <script language="JavaScript">
  var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  mydiv.innerHTML = mydiv.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('test', 'g'), "<em>test</em>");
 </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

GWT:

```
content.setInnerHTML(contentString.replaceAll("test", "<em>test</em>"))
```